# How to remove specific characters from string C#

Tags: c#

```
string s1 = "Tetrabenazine 12.5mg";    
string s2 = "Hydroxyzine 10mg HCL Tabs";  
string s3 = "Abacavir Tablets 300mg"; 
string s4 = "Quinapril HCTZ 10/12.5mg"; 

S1 = "Tetrabenazine";    
S2 = "Hydroxyzine HCL Tabs";    
s3 = "Abacavir Tablets";  
s4 = "Quinapril HCTZ";
```

I have a set of strings with different patterns as above (String declarations).
I need to achieve a string result set as declared above.
Please help me to find out the solution for this as i'm new to C#.

i have tried in different ways like

1. `String.Trim()`
2. `Regex.Replace(itemname, @"[0-9\-]", string.Empty);`
3. `Regex.Replace(itemname, "mg", string.Empty);`

Which has not helped me. So please give me the solution

Answer (score 3):

use Regular Expression for that

```
string s1 = "Tetrabenazine 12.5mg";
s1 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"[ \d\./]+mg", "");
```

Comment: i have tried your solution  but it was not worked for me

Comment: what is the error / result you get?

Comment: sorry for the thing the solution is  was working fine after making the slight change as itemname = Regex.Replace(itemname, @"[0-9\-]+mg", "");

Comment: you're welcome, accept my answer when it is correct for you

Answer (score 0):

I understood your Question, so you want to remove the numeric values present in the string. i hope u are working for some medical oriented projects.,

solution:
1.You have to find the POSITION of numeric value present in string.(say a)
2.if yes, from that position find the empty space position.(say b)
3. remove the string from the position from a to b.

I hope this would be clear. if u want addition information. let me know